# Occasional "EntityValidationErrors" on asp.net, EF6, web forms app, hosted onAzure requiring server restart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure-web-app-service

Site has been running well for 2+ years, however in the last few weeks "EntityValidationErrors" have started occurring 1-5x per day. The errors only affect login and signup operations, and users already logged in can continue using data driven site. Typical validation error is *"The field UserName must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '50'"*. Server metrics look normal. After restarting app, identical signup form inputs succeed. I am confused why this started occurring randomly in what had been stable app.

There has been recent uptick in SQL Injection attempts, but I don't believe any have been successful and probably coincidental.

Any suggestions as to what might be the cause would be much appreciated.

Comment: Error which you are getting is because of a setting like this : Property(m => m.UserName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50); , Could you please check if someone is trying to access the login window and providing the user name more than 50 char

Comment: The interface limits input length to 50. chars--the reported error is misleading. Exact same user signup inputs work after server restart.